# CreateFile ,ReadDirectoryChanges issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, createfile, readdirectorychangesw

I’m using `ReadDirectoryChangesW` to spy a folder that I opened with `CreateFile`, once a file was added I call a function (`OnFileChanged`) that read the size and open it for reading, my application works fine for small sized file but the problem occurs when I try to copy a big file into my folder(7,24 M), and I get `Permission denied` error after calling fopen to read it.

the watching process is based on [this](http://sumatrapdf.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/FileWatch.h)

```
    void Init(const QString FullPath)
    {    ...
         hDir = CreateFile(
                dirPath, // pointer to the directory containing the tex files
                FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY|GENERIC_READ,                // access (read-write) mode
                FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_DELETE|FILE_SHARE_WRITE,  // share mode
                NULL, // security descriptor
                OPEN_EXISTING, // how to create
                FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS  | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED , // file attributes
                NULL); // file with attributes to copy


            SecureZeroMemory (&overl, sizeof(overl));
            SecureZeroMemory(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            overl.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);

            // watch the directory
           BOOL res= ReadDirectoryChangesW(
                 hDir, /* handle to directory */
                 &buffer[curBuffer], /* read results buffer */
                 sizeof(buffer[curBuffer]), /* length of buffer */
                 FALSE, /* monitoring option */
                 FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME ,
                 //FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE, /* filter conditions */
                 NULL, /* bytes returned */
                 &overl, /* overlapped buffer */
                 NULL); /* completion routine */

    }

void StartWatchThread()
{
    // if the thread already exists then stop it
    if (IsThreadRunning())
        SynchronousAbort();

    //CrashIf(!hDir);
    if(!hDir)
       { qDebug()<<" handle "<<hDir<<" last error"<<GetLastError();
        exit(-1);}

    else
    {// reset the hEvtStopWatching event so that it can be set if
    // some thread requires the watching thread to stop
    ResetEvent(hEvtStopWatching);

    DWORD watchingthreadID;
    qDebug()<<"befrore creating thread";
    hWatchingThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, WatchingThread, this, 0, &watchingthreadID);
    qDebug()<<"watchingthreadID"<<watchingthreadID;
    }
}


DWORD WINAPI WatchingThread(void *param)
{
    //qDebug()<<"in WatchingThread";
    FileWatcher *fw = (FileWatcher *)param;

    HANDLE hp[2] = { fw->hEvtStopWatching, fw->overl.hEvent };
    for (;;)
    {

        DWORD dwObj = WaitForMultipleObjects((sizeof(hp)/(sizeof(hp[0])))
                                             , hp, FALSE, INFINITE);
        if (dwObj == WAIT_OBJECT_0) // the user asked to quit the program
        {
            qDebug()<<"in WatchingThread the user asked to quit the program";
            //exit(-1);
            break;
        }
        if (dwObj != WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1)
        {
            // BUG!
            //assert(0);
            qDebug()<<"dwObj "<<dwObj<<" last error "<<GetLastError();
            break;
        }
        //qDebug()<<"WatchingThread fw->NotifyChange() ";

        //if (fw->wakeup)
            fw->NotifyChange();

    }
    return 0;
} 


bool NotifyChange()
{
    //qDebug()<<"in NotifyChange";

    GetOverlappedResult(hDir, &overl, &dwNumberbytes, FALSE);

    FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION *pFileNotify = (FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION *)buffer[curBuffer];
    // Switch the 2 buffers
    curBuffer = (curBuffer + 1) % (sizeof(buffer)/(sizeof(buffer[0])));
    SecureZeroMemory(buffer[curBuffer], sizeof(buffer[curBuffer]));
    // start a new asynchronous call to ReadDirectory in the alternate buffer
    ReadDirectoryChangesW(
         hDir, /* handle to directory */
         &buffer[curBuffer], /* read results buffer */
         sizeof(buffer[curBuffer]), /* length of buffer */
         FALSE, /* monitoring option */
         FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME  ,
         //FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE, /* filter conditions */
         NULL, /* bytes returned */
        &overl, /* overlapped buffer */
         NULL); /* completion routine */

    // Note: the ReadDirectoryChangesW API fills the buffer with WCHAR strings.
    for (;;) {

        if (pFileNotify->Action == FILE_ACTION_ADDED)
        {
            qDebug()<<"in NotifyChange if ";
                char szAction[42];
                char szFilename[MAX_PATH] ;
                memset(szFilename,'\0',sizeof( szFilename));
                strcpy(szAction,"added");
                wcstombs( szFilename, pFileNotify->FileName, MAX_PATH);

                OnFileChanged(szFilename,szAction);
                qDebug()<<"in NotifyChange after OnFileChanged ";

        }

        // step to the next entry if there is one
        if (!pFileNotify->NextEntryOffset)
            return false;
        pFileNotify = (FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION *)((PBYTE)pFileNotify + pFileNotify->NextEntryOffset);
    }
    pFileNotify=NULL;
    return true;
}
```

I couldn't figure out how is handling the file and don't let me read it?
I tried to call Sleep() after calling `OnFileChanged` and wake up when it finish but in vain. 
Any idea please .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I call a function (OnFileChanged) that read the size and open it for reading

That is pretty much guaranteed to fail sooner or later.  File-changed notifications are generated *while* a process is writing to the file.  Which prevents you from opening the file if the process hasn't completed writing yet or is otherwise keeping the file open.  And didn't permit read sharing, very common for programs that write a file.  It is certainly related to file size, the larger the file, the longer it takes to write so the greater the odds you are trying to open it while the other process didn't close it yet.

You'll need to deal with this possible mishap.  Nothing you can do but keep the path in a queue so you can try later.

Comment: Thank you @Hans, so there is no chance to get a notification when the process finish writing? I need to know when a file was added to my folder to treat it immediately so if I keep file path in a queue and treat it later I will lose the real-time feature of my application, what do you suggest ? how to know that a file is free so I can wait it to be and call my treatment ? thanks again.

Comment: No.  You know by successfully opening the file.  You'll have to repeatedly try.  This is no different from any other file system operation.  It is just more likely that a process has a lock on the file when you use this api.

Comment: ok i will try to loop until open it successfully, thank you for your time @Hans.

Comment: with with period? how to know how much it took to release my file?

Comment: You cannot know of course.  First make sure it doesn't matter that you get it a couple of seconds later.  If it does then you need a fundamentally different approach.  If it doesn't then pick a number, any number, above one second.  The bigger the typical file, the bigger the number.  It isn't critical because you'll of course put the file back in the queue if it fails the next time.

Comment: I tried to sleep 5 sec and reopen it again ti works and for my file 7,24M it took 10s approximately to be opened successfully.